# Is there a way to get device display size or screen resolution from firebase data?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I want to get device display size and screen resolution info from firebase data so I know what displays to focus on for design and tech issues. However, I can't find this info anywhere. I know screen resolution is available in Google Analytics but has anyone seen it in Firebase?

I've checked the schema and doesn't seem to be there automatically but wondering if I've missed something or there is a way to get it to populate somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That information is not collected automatically.  You can certainly collect display information yourself using whatever APIs are provided by the host operating system, and add them as a [user property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/user-properties), which will be available when you export data to BigQuery.